# Converting Dictionary to Json to pass parameters in Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, swift3

I have a dictionary with key as username and value as email. Which i would like to send to an api using Alamofire i have no clue how to approach this problem as i am suppose to send multiple users to the api to save at once.

**Dictionary**

```
var selectedMembers = [String: String]()
```

The data saved in this dictionary is appended in a different VC from a table view where we can choose how many users we want to append in the dictionary. 
Now i need to convert this dictionary into json formate to send to the api through alamofire.

**Json Formate**

```
"users": [
        {
          "user_email": "abc@gmail.com",
          "user_name": "abc"
        }, 
        {
          "user_email": "abc2@gmail.com",
          "user_name": "abc2"
        }   
   ]
```

**Alamofire Code**

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "users" : [
               [
                "user_name" : "user_name goes here",
                "user_email" : "user_email goes here"
               ]
            ]
        ]

        Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

        }
```

**How i solved the Problem**

i created a function that prints the the data how i want it and placed it in Alamofire parameters something like this.

```
var selectedMembers = [String: String]()
var smembers = [AnyObject]()
var selected = [String: String]()

if selectedMembers.isEmpty == false {
        for (key, value) in selectedMembers {
            selected = ["useremail": key, "catagory": value]
            smembers.append(selected as AnyObject)
        }
    }

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: smembers, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

let parameters: Parameters = [
            "users" : jsonString as AnyObject
        ]

        Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make Array of dictionary(user) as of currently you are setting `user`'s value as `Dictionary` instead of `Array`.

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "users" : [
        [
            "user_name" : "abc",
            "user_email" : "abc@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "user_name" : "abc2",
            "user_email" : "abc2@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
]
Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

}
```

Comment: Yeah thats a mistake but my question is what if there are 2 or 3 users in the dictionary, how do i change number of parameters going in with data from the dictionary

Comment: ok so the data in the dictionary changes. it comes from a list where i can choose to append any number of items in the Dictionary.

Comment: @AmanChawla If it still not working try adding `encoding` argument also in request call with `JSONEncoding.default` value like this `Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            
        }`

Comment: i have added how i want to approach this problem

Comment: @AmanChawla Why are you making dictionary with `email` and `catagory` instead of `user_email` and `user_name` also can you show the log for `selectedMembers` dictionary.

Comment: i think i was not able to explain what i really wanted to do but i found the solution now which was converting dictionary to json string using json serialization. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @AmanChawla Ok its great that you made it but what I don't get is why you are making JSON string when you need to pass dictionary with `Alamofire`.

Comment: The data in the dictionary is dynamic(the user chooses that data from a tableview which is also dynamic depending on how many friends he has). So there is no particular number of useremails and usernames that go to alamofire that data goes to my api and sends invitation to selected people by user.

Comment: @AmanChawla I'm not talking about dynamic data that you can add in your `users` array as many as you want what i'm saying is what is the need of to create JSON string when you need to pass a dictionary in `Alamofire`

Comment: How else would i pass dynamic data to alamofire?

Comment: @AmanChawla You just need to make one array with your dynamic data and when you call request with `Alamofire` pass simple one dictionary like `let let parameters: Parameters = ["users": yourUsersDynamicArray]` thats it

Comment: I thought of doing the same but the api is not accepting that response for some reason.

Comment: @AmanChawla Edit your question with your current code that is working with `JSON` string that will give us idea which one is working and how it is working

Comment: look at this post....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878960/sending-post-request-to-api-using-alamofire

Answer (score 0):

If your web API demands the post data to send in JSON format then below written method is a way to do this.

```
func calltheAPIToSendSelectedUser () {
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "users" : [
            [
                {
                    "user_name" : "user1_name goes here",
                    "user_email" : "user1_email goes here"
                },
                {
                    "user_name" : "user2_name goes here",
                    "user_email" : "user2_email goes here"
                },
                {
                    "user_name" : "user3_name goes here",
                    "user_email" : "user3_email goes here"
                },
            ]
        ]
    ]

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "YourApiURL")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that worked for invoking POST using Alamofire and passing in an array of dictionary values as the Parameters arg. 
Notice the 'User' key which contains a dictionary of values.

```
    let dict: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
    dict["facebook_id"] = "1234559393"
    dict["name"] = "TestName"
    dict["email"] = "TestEmailID"

    let params: Parameters = [
        "user": dict
    ]

    Alamofire.request("YOURURL", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("succeeded in making a Facebook Sign up REST API. Now going to update user profile"
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                return
                    print(error)
            }
        })
```

Right at the point where you are adding items to the dictionary, is where you can check for nil values and avoid adding as needed, thus making it dynamic.