# Sending POST request to API using Alamofire

Tags: arrays, json, swift3, alamofire

So Im using an API for an app that helps me store data for events where i send data to the API entered/selected by the user store it and get back an ID to reference to later.
Here is some code that Im using.

**JSON accepted by API**

```
    {
   "topic":"test shedule",
   "setdate":"21-09-2017",
   "scheduledate":"22-09-2017",
   "settime":"09:00:00",
   "scheduletime":"10:00:00",
   "agenda":"hi this is test agenda",

   "adminname":"name",
   "type":"meeting",
    "users": "[{\"category\":\"optional\",\"email\":\"abc@gmail.com\"}]",
   "adminemail":"abc@gmail.com"
 }
```

**Data Im Sending using Alamofire**\

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "topic":topicTextField.text!,
            "setdate":currentDate as String,
            "scheduledate":setDate as String,
            "settime":currentTime as String,
            "scheduletime":setTime as String,
            "agenda":agendaTextField.text!,
            "adminname":"abcname",
            "type":"meeting",
            "users" : "\(smembers)",
            "adminemail":"abc@gmail.com"
        ]

        Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)meeting_shedule.php",method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
            if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let topic = dict["topic"] as? String
                let g_id = dict["g_id"] as? String

                self.storeMeeting(topic: topic!, g_id: g_id!)

            }
        }
```

**smembers is an array created from the dictionary selectedMembers and the dictionary selectedMembers comes from a different ViewController by using prepare for segue**

```
    var selectedMembers = [String: String]()
    var smembers = [Any]()
    var selected = [String: String]()

if selectedMembers.isEmpty == false {
            for (key, value) in selectedMembers {
                selected = ["email":key, "category":value]
                smembers.append(selected)
            }
        }
```

**The Problem**

Im facing a failure response from api. 
i think the problem is sending "users" to the API as the API is asking for data in string form and Im sending an array i have even tried to solve this problem by converting smembers to jsonstring by serialization but still returns failure.

**Image of error Im receiving** 
[image]

The api works when Im sending request through post man like this. 
[image]

I have no clue how to approach this problem, how to send the data that the API will accept.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change logic in as shown bellow

```
  var selectedMembers = [String: String]()
    var smembers = [String]()
    var selected = ""

if selectedMembers.isEmpty == false {
            for (key, value) in selectedMembers {
                selected = String(format: "{\"\\email\\\":\"\\%@\"\\,\"\\category\"\\:\"\\%@\"\\}", arguments: [key,value])
                smembers.append(selected)
            }
        }
```

Then in ur post data

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "topic":topicTextField.text!,
            "setdate":currentDate as String,
            "scheduledate":setDate as String,
            "settime":currentTime as String,
            "scheduletime":setTime as String,
            "agenda":agendaTextField.text!,
            "adminname":"abcname",
            "type":"meeting",
            "users" :"[\(smembers.joined(separator: ","))]",
            "adminemail":"abc@gmail.com"
        ]
```

Comment: The data coming from different VC is a dictionary storing data like selectedMembers = [email: category]. how does that data go into the class you have created i dont understand that?

Comment: show me the code how u passing info to that api call

Comment: oh its just a simple prepare for segue that transfers selectedMembers between ViewControllers look at the last code i have put in the post

Comment: use selected users here           "users" : User.jsonArrayFromModels(selectedUsers)

Comment: I have made some edits towards the end might help you understand my problem better.

Comment: still the response is failure, I have added image of error im receiving

Comment: Do you need to add "/" also in ur input JSON?

Comment: yes even postman is not accepting without those. API send back "Unexpected" without them.

Comment: hi @AmanChawla ur backed team  they accepting user as a string instead of an array of JSON so u have to make it as string, I updated code in my answer check it once